# problem in connectiong to imap server

Tags: php, imap

i have three hours trying to connect to imap server with php

but i got that error

```
Warning: imap_open() [function.imap-open]: Couldn't open stream {213.175.202.118:143}INBOX in /home/user/public_html/imap.php on line 3
```

my code is

```
$mbox = imap_open("{ip:143}INBOX", "user", "password");
```

The mail details above is valid .. i have created it to test it

you can test it easily from your localhost !

i have three hours replacing in imap link

like 
ip:143
imap.mydomain.com:143
etc ...

also i am sure i have imap installed on server .. <- i have Cpanel

problem Fixed !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try (from http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php); looks ssl related:

```
<?php 
imap_open( "{server.example.com:143/novalidate-cert}INBOX" , 'login' , 'password' ); 
?>
```

Comment: Finally ! connected .. thank you james and sorry for incoming users i will edit post and delete my information .. the problem was in user .. it should be user@domain.com